# Jquery : Same class number on two different links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function

```
$('.link1-**number**').click( function() {
    $(".link2-**number**").hide()
});
```

When I click on link1-**number** I want to hide link2-**number** but only if **number** are the same value.

So
`<a class="link1-1987">Link 1</a>`
Hides `<a class="link2-1987">Link 2</a>`

`<a class="link1-1">Link 1</a>`
Hides `<a class="link2-1">Link 2</a>`

`<a class="link1-5">Link 1</a>`
Hides `<a class="link2-5">Link 2</a>`

etc

Comment: Is what you want to have a link that contains a location for the user to be taken to, like a toc generated by software like wordpress?

Comment: Yes I'm using wordpress. It depend of the post_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for your edit:

```
$('a[class^=link1]').click(function(){
    var number = this.className.split('-')[1];
    $('a.link2-' + number).hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJtup/)

Note that it will work only if:

1. There is only one class for `link1` anchors.
2. That anchor doesn't have more than one hyphen.

Comment: @JohnS, Actually it's right as is. see the [problematic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJtup/1/) when the link1 has several classes.

Comment: I stand corrected. Honestly, I'm not sure what I was thinking. Thanks for putting together the example.

Answer (score 2):

Your question it too vague but I believe you're looking for that starts with selector:

```
$('a[class^="b-"]').click();
```

It will match all the `<a>` which have a class that starts with a `b-`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QP2sW/1/)

Comment: Well, Ok thank you for your answer (both of you). I'm going to clarify my question because this is not exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: @user1708580, Your edit is like a new question, I added a new answer for your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Using the selector from @gdoron, how about this:

```
$('a[class^="link1-"]').click(function() {
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    var i = className.indexOf('-');
    if (i >= 0) {
        var number = className.substring(i + 1);
        $(".link2-" + number).hide()
    }
});
```

Note: This works only if the "link1-###" elements have a single class name. It would have to be enhanced to support them having multiple class names, but even then the "link1-###" class name would have to come first.

[Live demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/7zS8x/)

**EDIT:** On second look, since the class names that match the selector must contain at least one dash, the code can be shortened to:

```
$('a[class^="link1-"]').click(function() {
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    var number = className.substring(className.indexOf('-') + 1);
    $(".link2-" + number).hide()
});
```

Comment: @gdoron, thanks, of course it uses your selector and you came up with the same idea.